# Is region bounded by curves always convex?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have region bounded by curves, for example https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/online-graphing-calculator/?uid=bxy6lnrrvi

Is it true that such region is always convex (in the sense that points of intersection form a convex set)?

Some counterexample?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not true. It is not even true in your example; the green region is not convex.

Comment: I'd go as far as claiming that a region like the one you shaded is never convex.

Comment: Why is it not convex? Points of intersection form convex set (ignore form of curves, connect points with straight lines).

Comment: The segment joining [point-very-close-to] $\left(\frac12, 6\right)$ to [point-very-close-to] $(3,3)$ intersect the part outside.

Comment: You mean (3/2, 6) ?